# video play directly from gallery

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary

I want to play video directly from gallery, i have written this code from which i can get both images and videos url but i am unable to play video automatically, any code or any help appreciated.

```
    ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        if (group) {
            [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allVideos]];
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
                if (asset){

                    NSDictionary *meta = [[asset defaultRepresentation] metadata];

                    if ([[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypeVideo]) {
                        // asset is a video
                        NSLog(@"See Asset: %@", asset);




                    }

//                    NSLog(@"%@",asset);
//                    NSLog(@"%@",meta);

                }
            }];
        }
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error enumerating AssetLibrary groups %@\n", error);
    }];
```

Comment: The code provided doesn't appear to be about playing video.

Comment: edited please check it

Comment: I still don't see it.  Once you have an asset url, you should be able to play with an MPMoviePlayer, giving it the contentURL.

Comment: can you please post the answer?

Comment: i can see my movie url in asset log message

Answer (score 0):

Include the MediaPlayer framework in the project, then in the view controller where you want to see the video:

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface MyViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *mp;
@end
```

Then, something like this to initialize it and add it's view to your hierarchy:

```
- (void)playUrl:(NSURL *)contentURL {

    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:contentURL];
    player.view.frame = // some CGRect here that fits your view

    [player prepareToPlay];
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];
    self.mp = player;
}
```